# How extract list of items from web page with selenium using python

Tags: python, selenium

I want to extract information from some site. The information that I want to extract is name of Items in list.

Here is example:

```
<body>
<div class = "_4gt3b">
    <ul class="_539vh _4j13h">
        <li class="_cx1ua">item 1</li>
        <li class="_cx1ua">item 2</li>
        <li class="_cx1ua">item 3</li>
        <li class="_cx1ua">item 4</li>
        <li class="_cx1ua">item 5</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I want extract "item 1,item 2,item 3,..." also I want consider class names "_4gt3b",""_539vh _4j13h","_cx1ua" because It is key to redirect the list of Items.

I use this code:

```
WebElement = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("._4gt3b._539vh._cx1ua")
```

But return:

```
>>> WebElement
[]
```

What is problem(s)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need spaces: `$('._4gt3b ._539vh ._cx1ua')`

Answer (score 1):

You can directly get the list of `li` by using this

`elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("/li[@class='_cx1ua']")`